# Running Meteor MeteorDB on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: mongodb, meteor, cloud9-ide

I am following [Meteor Tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections). So i started my application in console with

`meteor <app_name> --port $IP:$PORT`

The app ran successfully. Then i opened a new terminal and tried to connect with `MongoDB` by using command `meteor mongo` but it says app isn't running. I tried `meteor mongo --port $IP:$PORT` which resulted in same error. Then i tried `meteor mongo --url http://0.0.0.0:8080/` (this was the site which was output by mongo server when i ran it) ... I got the login prompt but i don't know what the user/password is

Comment: When you ran mongo on $IP:$PORT, that was the same port that meteor was running on from the start so I think that would be a conflict so you'll want to use 8081 or 8082 there.

Comment: As for the login screen, I can't easily tell if it's a Cloud9 login screen or a Mongo screen or a Meteor screen so maybe post a screenshot here so we can tell more easily. You may try your Cloud9 username and password or a blank password in the meantime.